# Azure IotHub routing is not functioning

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have the following routing query defined in Azure IotHub:
`$body.messageType="Test"`

And using `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client"` SDK  `Version="1.28.0"`

Here is my very simple C# code.

```
            var device = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString);
       
            await device.OpenAsync();

            var obj = new
            {
                messageType = "Test"
            };

            var telemetryJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(telemetryJson));

            // Set message body type and content encoding. 
            message.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
            message.ContentType = "application/json";

            await device.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Message gets delivered to IotHub but routing is not applied! Any idea why?

Comment: the routing query string is OK. Could you post the screen snippet of the Route details?

Comment: also, for test purpose, add the *Device Telemetry Messages* routing (true) to the storage blob. You should see the message body in the json formatted text, such as **{ "messageType":"Test" }**

Comment: also IoT Hub emits diagnostic logs for Routes which might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the IotHub resource's behavior was not normal at all. Different types of error messages started to appear like `IotHub is not in an Active state` whatsoever.

Deleting and recreating the resource resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it with single quotes like this `$body.messageType='Test'`?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed at times after creating new route , IOTHUB takes some time before I start seeing messages on storage container. Just give it half an hour and check again